# What happens with return value?

Tags: c++, pointers, return

So I have 2 classes for this example:
`E`, which prints a message when it is destroyed + can store integer value
`T`, which stores instance of `E` and can return it through a method

Code:

```
class E
{
public:
    E();
    ~E();
    int test;
};

E::E(){}
E::~E()
{
    std::cout << "E is destroyed" << std::endl;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////

class T
{
public:
    T();
    ~T();
    E data;
    E get();
};

T::T(){}
T::~T(){}
E T::get()
{
    return this->data;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////

int main()
{
    E e;
    e.test = 2;

    T t;
    t.data = e;

    E* e2;
    {      
        e2 = &(t.get());
        std::cout << "end of block" << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << e2->test;
}
```

Result of running my code is:

```
E is destroyed
end of block
```

which means that some instance of `E` is destroyed before reaching the end of `{}`

**Questions:**
1. I experimented a bit. Is it correct that `t.get()` value in `e2 = &(t.get());` line  is destroyed immediately because it was not assigned by value to any variable?
2. If this value is destroyed, that means that `e2` pointer is invalid. But `std::cout << e2->test;` line still prints saved integer value. Is pointer still valid somehow or this data just occassionally stayed at this place of memory?

Comment: Yes you have a [dangling pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer) to a variable that fell out of scope. Trying to do anything with that object after that point is undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that if your function had the signature `E& T::get()` you would return a reference to your `data` which is still in scope, so that would have been fine. The problem was that you returned an `E` by value, which was a temporary that was immediately destroyed.

Comment: @Cyber, yes, I was thinking this way, thanks. I had read something about temporaries, but was not sure if that was about my situation exactly. So, am I correct about this: if temporary is assigned by value to something immediately, it is not destroyed for sure, yes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original code won't compile by GCC because the function

```
E T::get()
{
    return this->data;
}
```

returns value. When you assign the pointer `e2 = &(t.get());` in the block, it makes a temporary copy of `data`. After you exit from the block, when you reference the pointer `e2`, it no longer points to the actual variable because the temporary variable is out of scope. So in order to correct this, you can modify the code to return a reference to `data` field of class `T`:

```
E& T::get()
{
    return data;
}
```

After that when you run the code again, you will see:

```
end of block
2
E is destroyed
E is destroyed
```

Note that the two `E is destroyed` is due to the fact that there are two `E` instances, one for `e`, and the other for `t.data` because the code `t.data = e;` will invoke the copy constructor of class `E`. Therefore finally there are two `E` objects get destructed when the program exits.

Answer (score 1):

By default, memory that is freed is not set to a specific value. Thus, it keeps the last value it had. What is happening is that the address of your **copy** of t->data is stored in e2. Then, the compiler frees said copy because you are not using it anymore. Thus you have a call to the destructor.

However, you are indeed keeping the values *in memory* so your pointer can still access them. (But i am guessing that with valgrind that is spitting out an invalid read.)

So yes, your pointer is indeed invalid, however it still can access the data.

Rephrased to answer logically your questions :

1) It's a copy and not assigned so destroyed immediately.

2) The values exist at the address however the address is considered invalid and can lead to memory issues (Segmentation fault for example)